# 'txtPackages' is not a member of 'VB_Access.form'

Tags: vb.net, forms

How can i add a member of packages which has the option of package 1 package 2 package 3 and package 4 I don't know how this is my code and it always says 'txtPackages' is not a member of 'VB_Access.form'

```
Public Class form
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    Me.txtCustID.Text = ""
    Me.txtFullName.Text = ""
    Me.txtPhone.Text = ""
    Me.txtAddress.Text = ""
    Me.txtPackages.Text = ""
    Me.txtCustID.Tag = ""
    'enable button edit
    Me.btnEdit.Enabled = True
    'set button add to add label
    Me.btnAdd.Text = "Add"
    '
    Me.txtCustID.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT stdid as [ID], " & _
                                         "stdname as [Name], Gender, Phone, Address " & _
                                         " FROM student ORDER BY stdid", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'fill data to datatable
    da.Fill(dt)

    'offer data in data table into datagridview
    Me.dgvData.DataSource = dt

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection if it is not yet open
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'check whether add new or update
    If Me.txtCustID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'add new 
        'add data to table
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO student(stdid, stdname, gender, phone, address) " & _
                        " VALUES(" & Me.txtCustID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtFullName.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.cboGender.Text & "','" & Me.txtPhone.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.txtAddress.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        'update data in table
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE student " & _
                    " SET stdid=" & Me.txtCustID.Text & _
                    ", stdname='" & Me.txtFullName.Text & "'" & _
                    ", gender='" & Me.cboGender.Text & "'" & _
                    ", phone='" & Me.txtPhone.Text & "'" & _
                    ", address='" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "'" & _
                    " WHERE stdid=" & Me.txtCustID.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    'refresh data in list
    RefreshData()
    'clear form
    Me.btnClear.PerformClick()

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub frmStudent_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\data.mdb"
    '
    'get data into list
    Me.RefreshData()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    'check for the selected item in list
    If Me.dgvData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.dgvData.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intStdID As Integer = Me.dgvData.SelectedRows(0).Cells("id").Value
            'get data from database followed by student id
            'open connection
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If
            'get data into datatable
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM student " & _
                                                 " WHERE stdid=" & intStdID, cnn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            Me.txtCustID.Text = intStdID
            Me.txtFullName.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("stdname")
            Me.cboGender.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("gender")
            Me.txtPhone.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("phone")
            Me.txtAddress.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("address")
            '
            'hide the id to be edited in TAG of txtstdid in case id is changed
            Me.txtCustID.Tag = intStdID
            'change button add to update
            Me.btnAdd.Text = "Update"
            'disable button edit
            Me.btnEdit.Enabled = False
            'close connection
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    'check for the selected item in list
    If Me.dgvData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.dgvData.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intStdID As Integer = Me.dgvData.SelectedRows(0).Cells("id").Value
            'open connection
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If

            'delete data
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM student WHERE stdid=" & intStdID
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'refresh data
            Me.RefreshData()

            'close connection
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label6.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VB_access.Form have txtpackages textbox or not?

Comment: I would suggest using parametrized queries. . .